# A version of TSP where there is a probability each node is visited?

Tags: graphs, optimization, traveling-salesman

A friend in industry proposed a problem to me. If you have a supply warehouse, you can treat each station with products as a node. Each node has a probability it will be visited by an employee working on an order. Is there a way to decide what product goes at each fixed node to minimize total travel time, by all employees over the course of a shift.

I'm assuming each employee starts and stops at the same spot. I can find an MST easily enough, and can use that as an upper and lower bound of tour time for one employee. Where I'm stuck is a way to rearrange the nodes, without just doing it randomly and brute forcing things.

So I will start with the number of nodes, and their physical distance apart. I will then be given a list of probabilities. Once the probabilities are assigned to each node, I can generate the expected length of a tour. I want to find out which assignment of probabilities to nodes generates the shortest expected length of a tour.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? What is the input and what is the desired output?

Comment: I've added details, please let me know if you have questions. Thanks in advance for the help!